# Possible to use websharper as a drop-in JS replacement?

Tags: javascript, f#, websharper

Is it possible to use websharper as a drop-in replacement for javascript without the additional complexity of sitelets or ASP.NET?

For example, can I compile the following websharper library to a .js file and call the hello() function from within a javascript script block in my html?

```
namespace WebSharperLib

open IntelliFactory.WebSharper

module HelloWorld =
  [<JavaScript>]
  let hello () =
    IntelliFactory.WebSharper.JavaScript.Alert("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed do something like that. The solution i found is as following :

- Create a WebSharper library project in VS
- Paste the code in your example
- Generate the solution
- Copy the last line of the solution generation (where it runs websharper) and run it in powershell/console just adding the option

  -js name of your js file

The thing is, this way you don't have any of the compiled dependencies. I guess you can get them if you make a full project and go grab the compiled js output there.

Tt seems to me WebSharper is not made to be used this way, but rather as a full package.

If you just want F# compilation to Javascript, there is [Pit](http://pitfw.org/) that is made exactly for that purpose, so i suggest you try that first.

Comment: It sounds like he's probably looking for something like Pit.

Comment: I am looking for something like Pit except it's full of bugs :)

Comment: If you copy the web sharper command and put it in a post-build script, and manage to include websharper's stdlib permanently you can probably have a good worklow with websharper and visual studio. Just takes some initial set up :)

Comment: Thanks, after a bit of messing around I've finally gotten this to work satisfactorily. In order to trigger the javascript to execute you need something like this:
`<script type="text/javascript">    this.IntelliFactory.Runtime.init[0]();     this.WebSharperLib.HelloWorld.hello();</script>`